# Segmented Progress Bar in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, progress-bar

I have a webpage where a user needs to enter data. Once they enter 10 items, they can continue.

I'm trying to create a progress bar to visually represent how many items they have entered/have left to enter.

Here is an image of what I'm trying to create

[image: segmented progress bar]

So far, the closest I've gotten is using Bootstrap's stacked progress bars. However, with the stacked bars, *the unfilled section is a single unbroken region* - it doesn't show how many segments are left. [Here's a fiddle showing what I mean.](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/9026/)

Here's the markup from the fiddle:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="progress progress-bar-segmented">
        <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 10%"></div>
        <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 10%"></div>
        <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 10%"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've searched for similar examples that could be adapted to meet my needs, but haven't had much luck. I'm also not sure exactly what I should be searching for or what to call this. Maybe this would be considered a step-wise progress bar?

Any help coming up with a solution would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, as you don't want the area inside the items to be filled percentually, I would recommend just creating ten empty divs side by side, and add the classes to fill them with color as the items are filled.

Just click to **Run code snippet** below and see what I mean.

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
}

.item {
    width: 10%;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    background-color: lightgray;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
}

.filled {
    background-color: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item filled"></div>
    <div class="item filled"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Use that bootstrap component only if you need to fill the divs **in percentual parts**. As for the styles, you can import the styles from bootstrap.

**BUT**, if you want very hard to **use the bootstrap component**, I have an ugly workaround [here](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/9028/).